# Can Powershell receive SignalR Hub messages?

Tags: powershell, signalr

I can use the SignalR client to send messages to a SignalR server hosted in a MVC4 application but I cannot receive messages from the server. Is this a problem with the PS threading model or I'm missing something?

Here is my code:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$PSScriptRoot\Bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll")) | Out-Null
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$PSScriptRoot\Bin\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.dll")) | Out-Null


function Test-SignalRHubProxy {
    $hubConn = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs.HubConnection -ArgumentList  "http://localhost:56811/" 
    $hubProxy = $hubConn.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub")
    $result = $hubConn.Start().Wait()
    $result = [Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs.HubProxyExtensions]::On($hubProxy, "addNewMessageToPage", [Action[String, String]] { 
        "received" | Out-Host # THIS LINE IS NEVER CALLED
    } )
    $hubProxy
}

$hp = Test-SignalRHubProxy
$hp.Invoke("Send", "John", "Hello") # OK
```

This code can be tested with the Microsoft example in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/older-versions/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc-4

Thanks in advance